# Right Circular Cylinder: Distance between axis and plan

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, problem-solving, angle

**B** is a point in the top **circle** of a *right circular cylinder*. **C** is a point in the bottom **circle** of the given cylinder. The angle between **[BC]** and the base's plan of the cylinder is **45 degrees**.
The **radius** of the cylinder is 25cm and **[BC]** is **14√2** cm.

Find the distance between the **axis** of this cylinder and the **plan** formed from the segment **[BC]** and which is parallel with the axis.

Comment: Impossible to determine with the information at hand. These constraints don’t prevent $BC$ from intersecting the axis, for instance.

Comment: @amd I'm not expert in Geometry but, I think that when it says the plan which is defined by *[BC]* is parallel with the *axis*, this means they don't intersect with one another.

Comment: My point is that $B$ and $C$ are not constrained enough by the problem statement to allow a unique solution: the length of the projection of $BC$ onto the base is much less than the diameter of the base. From this intersecting position, shift both points a small distance in the same direction. The resulting plane-axis distance is some small positive number. Now shift the points again by the same amount in the same direction: this doubles the previous plane-axis distance.

Comment: @amd If this helps you, I have the correct answer given in the book. It is *24 cm*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reasonable interpretation of the text is that point $B$ and $C$ lie on the circumference of the bases. Seen from "above", $BC$ is a chord of the base circle, with a length of $14\ $cm. Its distance from the center of the circle (i.e. from the axis) is thus $\sqrt{25^2-7^2}=24\ $cm.

Comment: How did you calculated the length of [BC] seen from the "above" equals to 14? And what does 7 represent? Please, take a look to the picture above, and suppose that that is the position of point *B* and *C*. Thank you.

Comment: You mean 14 cm is the projection of [BC] in the bottom base?

Comment: Yes, 14 cm is the projection of [BC] on the bottom base and 7 is one half of that. But if $B$ and $C$ are not on the perimeter of the bases, as it seems to be the case in your picture, then the information given is not enough. Given the answer, I presume my interpretation is correct.

Comment: You are right. Actually, the given problem says that B is in the upper $circle$ and C in the bottom one. This phrase means that they are in the parameter line. One last clarification... Is there a theoreme that says that the perpendicular radius cuts a segment between 2 different perimeter points of the circle in half?

Comment: Yes: it's the theorem stating that [in an isosceles triangle median and altitude relative to the base are the same](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Altitude,_Median_and_Perpendicular_Bisector_Coincide_iff_Triangle_is_Isosceles).